# php: command not found on centos

Tags: centos, mysql, php, nginx

I've currently installed CentOS (6.5 version), nginx, mysql and php. I've tried to navigate to  `index.php` in a browser, and it looks fine, but if I try to run the script via the command-line I get:

> php: command not found

Why did that happen? How can I solve it?

---

**Edit**: I tried to install the php-cli package:

```
# yum install php-cli
Error: Package: php-cli-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
           Installed: php-common-5.4.35-1.el6.remi.x86_64 (@remi)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.35-1.el6.remi
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-38.el6.x86_64 (base)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-38.el6
           Available: php-common-5.3.3-40.el6_6.x86_64 (updates)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.3.3-40.el6_6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to install the commandline interface version of php before you can use it from `bash`:

```
yum install php-cli
```

the commandline version is not necessary if PHP is part of a page in nginx.

Comment: See edited post